# how to store results of ./a.out to a text file in c++?

Tags: c++

I am wondering if there is any way to store the results of my program into a text file.
this is my program :

```
void
search(unsigned int k, mybit t, mybits &e, mybits &r) {
  if (k == e.size()) {
    r.push_back(t);
    return;
  }
  if (t & e[k]) {
    search(k + 1, t, e, r);
  } else {
    mybit v = e[k];
    while (v) {
      mybit t2 = v & -v;
      if (check_minimal2(t | t2, k + 1, e)) {
        search(k + 1, t | t2, e, r);
      }
      v = v ^ t2;
    }
  }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    std::cout << "usage: ./a.out inputfile "<< std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
  std::string filename = argv[1];
  mybits e;
  
  e = load_datfile(filename);
 
  mybits r;
  search(0, 0, e, r);
  
}
```

after I type:

make
!./a.out input2.dat

My algorithm is performed and the results are out.txt:

```
usage: ./a.out <inputfile> out.txt
```

Comment: Either open an output file stream that you can write results to, or pipe your results from stdout to a file from your shell. Worth noting, your `argc` check is wrong. You want 3 arguments, not 2. Finally, your code is not an [mre], as there are all kinds of functions being called that you're not showing.

Comment: This may help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file

Answer (score 0):

You could just use stdout and redirect your program output to a file.

In your code use

```cpp
std::cout << "Whatever you want to end up in you output file";
```

And then call it with

```bash
./a.out <input-file> > out.txt
```

Since stdout ends up in you file, you should probably use stderr for you error message:

```cpp
  if (argc < 2) {
    std::cerr << "usage: ./a.out inputfile "<< std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code already has a `load_datfile()` that you don't show here. In your exercise, you are supposed to write a `store_datfile()` function that writes a file similar how the inputfile is read. You then pass `r` as a const reference parameter to that function after calling `search`.

We don't know what the `mybits` type is and we are not supposed to write code for you.